# I can't trash files anymore, but only delete them directly

Tags: macos, trash

When I want to delete a file in Finder or in the Desktop a popup appears and it says it will be deleted immediately, and I need to confirm.

The trash is always empty, and I can't use it anymore.

What's going on with Snow Leopard and not having a working trash can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the ownership and permissions on `~/.Trash`.

```
mress:10039 Z$ ls -ld ~/.Trash 
drwx------  285 allbery  staff  9690 Jun 28 16:53 /Users/allbery/.Trash/
```

My guess is it somehow ended up being owned by `root`, but there are other possibilities.  If it's the owner, the fix is `sudo chown $USER ~/.Trash ~/.Trash/.DS_Store`.

Comment: It is indeed: drwx------  3 root  staff  102 Jun 27 08:52 /Users/aneuryzma/.Trash

Comment: @geekosaur Should I change the permissions to 777 ?

Comment: `sudo chown $USER ~/.Trash ~/.Trash/.DS_Store` is all you should need to do.

Comment: @geekosaur I get this: chown: /Users/Patrick/.Trash/.DS_Store: No such file or directory

Comment: That's harmless; the file will only exist if the Finder wanted to store extra information about the Trash itself.