# How to trash VLC

Tags: macos, trash

When I try to trash VLC it says it can't be deleted. Does anyone know how to do this. Also I can no longer see any of my other things on finder.

Comment: If I click the finder again, my original finder shows up but I still can't trash the VLC. I did empty my trash can.

Comment: Is the error moving the app into trash or is the error emptying trash. Each has different things that can block you. Editing in a specific error dialog or message might help is help you.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/i-cant-trash-files-anymore-but-only-delete-them-directly

Comment: @bmike, This question is almost 5 years old and as the user is unregistered and hasn't been seen since Last seen Nov 18 '15 at 13:49, it's  very doubtful the OP is coming back to this question or it's even an issue at this point in time. It was only brought to the top today because agruti sharma posted an answer that wasn't an answer.

Comment: I know - that's why I closed it. I don't think you're going to get a check and don't think leaving it open for more answers helps. (and leaving it open does hurt overall)

Comment: @bmike, I actually got two +1's out of it and I'll take it after the hit from the other day! :)

Answer (score 3):

I have no problem sending VLC.app ( the .app extension is hidden by default) to the Trash and then emptying the Trash.  Works just as intended.

You can try using [AppCleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to remove it or use the Terminal.

Open up a Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal) and type the following followed by a space:

`rm -r`

Then drag and drop the VLC application bundle onto the Terminal window.  The command line should look as follows:

`rm -r /Applications/VLC.app`

Now press Enter and the VLC application bundle should be removed.

If it persists then preface the command with `sudo` as in the following example:

`sudo rm -r /Applications/VLC.app`

When you press Enter then enter your password and press Enter again.  (This is assuming your Account is an Admin Account.)

You also can try `rm -rf /Applications/VLC.app`, with or without `sudo` as necessary, as the `-f` *option* will attempt to force removal.

**Note: Be extremely careful when using `rm` as removed files/folders are permanently deleted and not placed in the Trash.**  Additionally, using `sudo` should be used with caution as well.  The primary thing to look for is that there are no typos in the command line and it's targeting only what is relevant as used.

Comment: This is a great answer for what might be going on in the trash. The not seeing things in finder mean there’s other breakage, too so I’ve put this on hold. Too broad and not clear enough